# oracle number datatype issue

Tags: .net, database, oracle

I have a field in my table whose datatype is `NUMBER (16,2)`.

I am trying to insert

```
99999999999999.99
```

I am using `.NET` to call a procedure and inserting the value in the table.

So I am using Decimal (.NET Type) to take the value and sending it to Oracle Proc as `NUMBER` (OracleType). 
But somehow I am getting the rounded value from the proc i.e

```
100000000000000
```

It is happening just when the significant digit are 14 and more.

I tried different combination though `NUMBER(17,2)` but nothing working.

What could be the issue?

here is what I am using

```
Decimal numberField = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
OracleParameter oraPram;
            oraPram = new OracleParameter("paramName", OracleType.Number);
            oraPram.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            oraPram.Value = numberField;
```

And the table structure is

```
Id      ----  Number
Quant   ----- Number(16,2)
```

Comment: What is the actual code and the exact table structure that you are using?

Comment: Edited the question and added the code & structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with the level of details you provided, but I'm guessing the parameter type of the Oracle stored procedure you are using is NUMBER. It should be defined using the `%TYPE` attribute.

Comment: Parameters are defined using %TYPE